# Gnuplot connect points when no value

Tags: shell-script, gnuplot, line

I have below example,

```
1|5 
2|8 
3|1 
6|8 
7|5 
8|10
```

With below code the chart connects between 3 and 6 x data is there a way to plot zero values between 3 and 6 x data,

```
gnuplot << EOT
set datafile separator "|"
set grid
set key off
set yrange [0:10]
set xrange [0:10]
plot "test.jpeg" u 1:2 smooth frequency lw 1 linecolor rgb "blue"
EOT
```

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: [In gnuplot, how to plot with lines but skip missing data points?](https://superuser.com/questions/440947/in-gnuplot-how-to-plot-with-lines-but-skip-missing-data-points)

Comment: The thing is I can't edit the data to insert a blank line is there any other way @steeldriver